# Correlation structure in model residuals

Tags: r, mixed-model, residuals, autocorrelation, generalized-least-squares

I ran some analysis, and I would feel much more confident with the feedback of the community. I do not provide a MWE (but I would be glad to do so if you feel the need) as I consider this query more conceptual than purely code, but I provided pseudo-code below to illustrate my thought.

All codes and models were done within R. The gls models I describe here are integrated in a path analysis using `piecewiseSEM` in R, which is why I used `gls` rather than `pgls` models and maximum likelihood methods.

##### Background

I am modelling soil characteristics (let's call it the `soil` variable), under various plants species, against a set of plant traits (`traits`) and abiotic variables (`abiotic`), and at different sites. My data are hence hierarchically structured by the different species of plants (`species`), nested within the `site` variable (same species found at different sites).

I wished to take into account the phylogenetic relationship between the plant species I study (which, I believe, impact the soil characteristics), and thus used Generalised Least Square (gls) models, with a specified correlation structure based on the phylogenetic tree.
This gives me the following model structure:

```
gls.mod <- gls(soil ~ traits + abiotic, corr = Corr(~species|site), method = "ML")
```

##### Investigating the residual structure

From my previous experience, correlation structure and random effects are defined by the experience design. However, following [this reference](https://besjournals-onlinelibrary-wiley-com.univ-smb.idm.oclc.org/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00044.x), I wished to verify that the residuals of my model followed the phylogenetic structure of the plant species.
To do so, I used a linear regression, and fitted the residuals against the plants' species and site :

```
mod1 <- lm(soil ~ traits + abiot)
resmod <- lm(residuals(mod1) ~ species + site)
```

I checked the result of `resmod` using `anova`, confirming that `species` and `soil` explained a significant part of the residual variation of the model.

i) From this, can I conclude that the structure of my residuals is indeed structured by the last two variables? (not by the phylogenetic structure in itself of course, but by the species?)

Then, I compared my gls model with a mixed-effect linear model (lmer) of the following form:

```
lmer.mod <- lmer(soil ~ traits + site + (1|site/species))
```

And found that the AIC of the gls model was always higher than that of the mixed effect model `AIC(lmer.mod) < AIC(gls.mod)`

ii) Does this comparison makes sense, or am I completely missing the points behind these models ?

iii) Does the fact that lmer model perform better than the gls model mean that the structure of my residuals is better explained by allowing the means to vary for each category rather than by the specific genetic structure I specified?

I hope I made my point clear enough, and I will be pleased to provide any details. I am fairly new to Generalised Least Square (gls) models, and the math behind them brings me to the edge of my understanding, making me fear some deep mistakes.

Comment: You need to be carefull with AIC. AIC is a function of log-likelihood and different model functions can use different definitions of log-likelihood (different by a constant). Verify that the same definition is used. Your `lmer` model doesn't make sense. Grouping variables of a random effect can't also be fixed effects. I assume you mean `soil ~ traits + abiot + (1|site/species)` there.

Comment: There was indeed a typo in the lmer formula, which you guessed right. I edited my question in this sense.

Comment: I couldn't find the formulas behind R logLik.gls or other methods, but it is indeed specified in R `AIC` help that "Particular care is needed when comparing fits of different classes". I hence presume that answer to point ii) and iii) is that the comparison between `AIC(lmer.mod` and `AIC(gls.mod)` does not make sense. Thanks for highlighting this characteristic of log-likelihood calculation !

Comment: You could fit the LMM with `nlme::lme`. log-likelihoods within the nlme package are consistent.

Comment: Okay, excellent. But the,, does it make sense to use AIC to compare the way auto-correlation structure or random effect explain my models' residuals (point iii), mainly) ? As I still find `AIC(lme.mod) < AIC(gls.mod)`

Comment: I don't really understand why you are even considering AIC. I would just use a mixed-effects model. I also don't understand why you talk about autocorrelation or where the `Corr` function is defined. Your reference is behind a log-in screen.